# Display and hide scrollbar dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to know if it is possible (with CSS and Javascript) to show and hide dynamically a scrollbar in a web page. 
 Let's say that when the user presses S, the scrollbar appears, and then again, he presses the S key and the scrollbar disappears. 
 Is this dynamic show/hide thing possible? How could it be done?

Comment: on the <body> tag of any page with scroll... try doing "overflow-y: hidden;" ... you can read an event for a particular key you want which can toggle show/hide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that with jQuery.

Note that `83` is the `keyCode` for `'S'`.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', ev => {
  if(ev.which === 83) $('html').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
#longDiv {
  height: 200vh;
  background: gray;
}
.hidden ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='longDiv'></div>
```